# Best way to initialize & migrate a Postgresql schema in microservice

Tags: database, microservices

I am developing my first project using the microservices architecture. My first idea is to have a shared Postgres DB within a Docker container where each microservice of the system can have its own schema. What I am facing now is that I'm not sure how each microservice should initialize (create its own role) and migrate (so far I just create the schema, in future I would like to use a migration tool like Flyway) the DB. I have read many theories about this but none are suitable for what I (think I) need.

Problems I am facing:

1. Create the role for the microservice.

At this point I will need the username and password of the superuser (or a user with permissions to create roles). Problem: The executing of the container will always need the user and pass of the superuser.
This step is only needed at the very first time a microservice is deployed in the system so I do not think setting this step in the microservice startup makes much sense. Problem: Every time the container is started the creation of the role will be performed.

2. Migrate the microservice's DB (its schema within the DB).

Same an before, this will be rarely be necessary (at least in theory) so I don't think it is a good idea to set it up at the startup of the container. Problem: Every time the container is started the migration will take place before the app starts, something unnecessary in most of the cases as the DB schema should change from time to time.

I will not use Kubernetes or any orchestrator tool... at least for now.

Any thoughts from experts in this field?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's NOT a specific programming issue, but a design issue. It may have a place under another tag, but I don't know which.

Comment: @Belayer perhaps you're right and this has nothing to do with Postgresql specifically. I just wanted to emphasize that I was using a system-wide database with one schema per service.

Comment: Understood. That is exactly why it doesn't belong. See [What topics ...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).